# stuck on adding a timer to my keyboard press program

Tags: python, keyboard

Im making a keyboard program that repeatedly presses a key every 0.1 seconds and uses esc as the hotkey to stop/start the program.

```
import keyboard
import time

keyboard.wait('esc')

name = ("python")

while name == "python":
keyboard.press_and_release('5')
time.sleep(0.1)

#this is where i want to add the timer

name = ("notpython")
```

I want to add the timer there so that after a few seconds the name variable changes from python to notpython and making the while loop false.

I've tried the time sleep function but it keeps printing 5 and doesnt stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try something like this:

```
import keyboard
import time

keyboard.wait('esc')
name = ("python")
timer = time.time()

while name == "python":
    keyboard.press_and_release('5')
    time.sleep(0.1)

    timer2 = time.time()
    if timer2 - timer >= 5: name = "notpython"
```

Comment: Why the use of `name == "python"` instead of a boolean? Or `while True` and a conditional `break`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).